# Most frequent word display

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, lexicographic

I have a problem because I only take 60 points per evaluation, I do not know how to display the lexicographic minimum if I have for example two words the same number of times.
I practically have to display the most common word in a text, if there are two words that appear the same number of times to display the lexicographic minimum.
I don't really know how to use HashMap to do this, a fix?
This is my code!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map < String, Integer > map = new LinkedHashMap < String, Integer > ();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String currentLine = reader.readLine();
        while (currentLine != null) {
            String[] input = currentLine.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase().split(" ");
            currentLine.replace('\n', ' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                if (map.containsKey(input[i])) {
                    int count = map.get(input[i]);
                    map.put(input[i], count + 1);

                } else {
                    map.put(input[i], 1);
                }

            }
            currentLine = reader.readLine();
        }
        String mostRepeatedWord = null;
        int count = 0;
        for (Map.Entry < String, Integer > m: map.entrySet()) {
            if (m.getValue() > count) {
                mostRepeatedWord = m.getKey();
                count = m.getValue();
            }
            else if (m.getValue() == count) {
                mostRepeatedWord = m.getKey();
                count = m.getValue();
                if ()
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mostRepeatedWord);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thought (there's probably better solutions): Instead of `map.entrySet()`, do `new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());`, and then sort it.  Then while you're iterating through the `keys` you can just _not_ replace the entry `if (m.getValue() == count)`.

Comment: That didn't work very well ... someone recommended me to use compareTo (), but I don't realize how I could use it in this situation to display the lexicographic minimum.

Comment: What do you mean 'that didn't work very well'?  It should work fine.  For the `compareTo` version suggested (somewhere): when doing `else if (m.getValue() == count) { ... }`, you could add an extra condition of `m.getValue().compareTo(mostRepeatedWord) < 0`.  This will _only_ replace the current `mostRepeatedWord` if the new one is lexicographically first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also compare the `mostRepeatedWord` with current key in case of a tie in the loop itself like below:

```
String mostRepeatedWord = null;
int count = 0;
for (Map.Entry < String, Integer > m: map.entrySet()) {
    if (m.getValue() > count) {
        mostRepeatedWord = m.getKey();
        count = m.getValue();
    } else if (m.getValue() == count) {
        String key = m.getKey();
        if ( key.compareTo(mostRepeatedWord) ) < 0 {
            mostRepeatedWord = key;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, is great. Another simple question, if I have more blank lines, will not display anything, what condition should I put in order to remove the empty lines?

Comment: @KoalaTHEGOD you need to show your input sample in order to provide right answer.

Comment: I put an input below.

Comment: I edited the code above, with currentline but it does not work, was I wrong in the implementation?

Comment: @KoalaTHEGOD you need to reassign the replaced string, ( string is immutable in Java ). `currentLine = currentLine.replace('\n', ' ');`